# Why I add one more col in bootstrap, It goes down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

![enter image description here][1]

When I add col number 1, col number 2 goes down. If I delete col number 1, col number 2 It goes up simple like col number 3. I do not know what happen with this?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="left"></span></div>
  <div  class="col-xs-8 row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:595px;border: 1px solid black;"> <span class="center"></span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:205px;border: 1px solid blue;"> <span class="center"></span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="right"></span></div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you show us your code :)

Comment: <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="left"></span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="height:595px;border: 1px solid black;">
    <span class="center"></span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="height:205px;border: 1px solid blue;">
    <span class="center"></span></div>

    <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="right"></span></div>
  </div>

Comment: Could u give me your email sir. I will sent the file zip to u?

Comment: Why would you do this, and why would someone open a random zip file? If this is relevant to the question, post it there, so everyone else, maxbe in the future, can recognize what's the problem of the question.

Comment: you are missing one div bro.. just add it..
<div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="left"></span></div><div class="col-xs-8"> <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:595px;border: 1px solid black;"> <span class="center"></span></div> <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:205px;border: 1px solid blue;"> <span class="center"></span></div></div> <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="right"></span></div> </div>

Comment: Thz bro it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you might be adding the col1 in same div with col2.
Your division should be

```
<div><!-- left section -->
col-3
</div>
<div><!-- center section -->
col-1
</div>
<div><!-- right section -->
col-2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don’t want your columns to simply stack in some grid tiers? Use a combination of different classes for each tier as needed. See the example below for a better idea of how it all works.**

learn it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8">.col-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">.col-6</div>
  <div class="col-6">.col-6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change your html

**To**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="left"></span></div>
  <div  class="col-xs-8 row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:595px;border: 1px solid black;"> <span class="center"></span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:205px;border: 1px solid blue;"> <span class="center"></span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:800px;border: 1px solid red;"><span class="right"></span></div>

</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36604/)..

Comment: It goes up sir but now got a problem with line

Comment: May give me your email? I send this file to u? Kindly help me

Comment: @Phantih what line?

Comment: It contains two line sir. It maybe cuz my css

Comment: @Phantih ask again another question about the problem and put all the necessary code.

Comment: here sir my css...@media screen and (max-width: 242px)
  {
  .container-fluid
  {
    height:245px;
    width:280px;
  }
  }
  .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-8
  {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .col-xs-2 span.left:after {content:'Left side';}
  .col-xs-2 span.right:after {content:'Right Side ';}
  .col-xs-8 span.center:after {content:'Center';}

Comment: @Phantih add another question here in the site.. We can't help you if your problem is unclear..